# Set LB1 and LB2 low on Arduino and ATmega

Tags: arduino, atmega, isp, security

I have searched for a possibility to objdump microcontrollers. I then have found this [post.](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/53282/protecting-avr-flash-from-reading-through-isp) There it says that LB1 and LB2 can be set to low to prevent the most people to read from it.

My questions is how to and is it possible to set this bits low for an Arduino and for an ATmega which is programmed via an Arduino.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lock bits can only be set via ISP, HVSP, or HVPP. There is no provision for setting the lock bits via the Arduino IDE even when a programmer is used; they must be set using AVRDUDE or a comparable tool.

Comment: IIRC there is a GUI tool from Atmel, so it isn't just command line.

Comment: Well, there is Atmel Studio, but that's a bit overkill for just setting a lock bit or two.

Comment: Yes, that too. Though I was thinking of the little GUI tool that supports setting fuses. The OP uses the Arduino IDE, so I think it is worth mentioning GUIs too.